# Running a similar App Scripts code on Multiple Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Just started to use App Scripts recently (Beginner programmer here).
I'm trying to automate the creation of a column + transposition of data from column B to newly created column C.

It's working fine, but when I try to replicate the script on multiple sheets, only one of the script works.

Below is my code (I tried to duplicate my constants to replicate the first script but then the first script does not work anymore. I guess I'm doing it the wrong way) :

```
// First script working fine.
const ss_1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet_1 = ss_1.getSheetByName('Marketing Report'); 

  function insertColumn() {
  const range_1 = sheet_1.getRange('B1:B300').getValues();
  const newrange_1 = sheet_1.getRange('C1:C300');
  const tmp_1 = new Date();
  const yesterday_1 = new Date(tmp_1.setDate(tmp_1.getDate()-1));
    
  sheet_1.insertColumnAfter(2);
  newrange_1.setValues(range_1);
  sheet_1.getRange('B2').setValue(yesterday_1).setNumberFormat("MMMM");
  }

// Second script, I tried to duplicate my constants to replicate the first script but then the first script does not work anymore. I guess I'm doing it the wrong way
const ss_2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet_2 = ss_2.getSheetByName('Sales Report'); 

  function insertColumn() {
  const range_2 = sheet_2.getRange('C1:C150').getValues();
  const newrange_2 = sheet_2.getRange('D1:D150');
  const tmp_2 = new Date();
  const yesterday_2 = new Date(tmp_2.setDate(tmp_2.getDate()-1)); 

  sheet_2.insertColumnAfter(3);
  newrange_2.setValues(range_2);
  sheet_2.getRange('C2').setValue(yesterday_2).setNumberFormat("MMMM");
  }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Hello Damien, I noticed that both functions have the same function name. Have you tried renaming one of them? Also, i would like to note that Google Apps Script can only run one function at a time (not unless you set the functions with triggers to run at the same time). I tried running both functions in my side (with different function names) and both functions worked fine. Can you explain how you are running the second script for the other sheets?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your answer.
If only one function can run at a time, that might be why my script is not working.

I'm currently trying to run both functions at the same time in one project (a single spreadsheet). I've tried to rename one of the function, but still only the first time works (I'm not getting any error though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, try to rename one of the functions in your script since they both have the same name. Don't forget to hit save. Please take note that Google Apps Script can run one function at a time (not including triggers). You can toggle through your functions through the dropdown menu (between the "Debug" and "Execution Log" buttons) to change to the function you would like to run. Make sure that both functions have different names.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick! Indeed I didn't realize that App Scripts could run only one function at a time.
1) I renamed one of the function to insertColumn2
2) I nested both function under a "master function"
function master (){
  insertColumn();
  insertColumn_2();} so I can run both functions at the same time